# How to make HTML5 validation work with IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, cross-browser, validation

I have html5 form validation, It works fine in chrome and firefox but not in IE. I prefer HTML5 than jquery because its simple to use. Is there any workaround to make the validation work in IE.

Comment: You could use `Modernizr.js` to make a proper validation for all of those browsers who don't support HTML5 forms.

Comment: @Vinay, check [formality](http://lingerbird.com/projects/open-source/formality/) jQuery plugin. You only have to include its JavaScript on your page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE < 10 is not compliant with HTML5, IE10+ or Edge is the only one that will have full support for HTML5.

I guess you should stay with jQuery for a while.

Comment: There is a JavaScript library [formality](http://lingerbird.com/projects/open-source/formality/) which helps you in this case. You don't have to setup any extra JavaScript for it. Adding HTML5 attributes to inputs and forms will make formality handle validation automatically if browser doesn't support HTML5. There are some options too.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the htmlshiv script? It's hosted on Google code projects and can be added to the head of your html files like so:

```
<!--[if lte IE9]>
    <script src="location/of/script" type="text/javascript"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Source: http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/

Comment: Validation does not work, I think styling issues of HTML5 can work in IE